# Ambiguous Invocation on Generic ContinueWith

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, asynchronous, lambda, task-parallel-library

I'm writing a simple C# console application that uses Asynchronous Tasks and Entity Framework (with the intent to run it under Linux (RHEL) with Mono, but that's a whole other challenge).  Note that I'm targeting .NET 4.0, so I'm using `.ContinueWith()` instead of `await`.

This, plus the EF DB model of a Northwind Database, is the entirety of the application:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MonoEF
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Model.NorthwindEntities _db = new Model.NorthwindEntities();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                GetCustomerNamesAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
                    if (t.IsFaulted) Console.WriteLine(t.Exception.Flatten.ToString);
                        else if (t.IsCompleted) foreach (string result in t.Result) Console.WriteLine(result);
                    });

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static Task<string[]> GetCustomerNamesAsync()
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => (from c in _db.Customers select c.ContactName).Distinct().ToArray());
        } 

    }
}
```

The problem is I'm getting the following error at the `.ContinueWith()`:

```
Ambiguous Invocation:
  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ContinueWith(System.Action<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string[]>>) (in class Task<string[]>)
  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ContinueWith(System.Action<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>) (in class Task)
match
```

To me, the invocation shouldn't be ambiguous, the compiler should prefer the generic Task over the non-generic Task, especially as it's the output of `GetCustomerNamesAsync()`.  However, as a VB.NET developer, I'm probably relying on `Option Infer` in this situation.

How would I go about explicitly letting the compiler know which invocation I want it to use in C#?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try explicitly specifying the lambda parameter type, like this:

```
.ContinueWith((Task<string[]> t) => { ... })
```

This problem with the way you were calling it is that `Task<TResult>` and `Task` (its base class) both have a `ContinueWith` method that looks almost the same:

```
Task<TResult>.ContinueWith(Action<Task<TResult>> action)
Task<TResult>.ContinueWith(Action<Task> action) //inherited from `Task`
```

Without specifying the input type of the `action`, the compiler can't determine which overload you want.  Explicitly providing the `action` lambda's input parameter type resoles this ambiguity.

---

It certainly would be nice if the compiler could assume the version that takes `Action<Task<TResult>> action`. Maybe someone else has an idea for how to get that kind of behavior?

---

## For posterity...

In the comments you'll see that MCattle found that he was only encountering this issue because of some compiler oddity related to missing parentheses on a method call inside of his lambda.  In general, you shouldn't need to explicitly specify the `Task<TResult>` type when passing the lambda to `ContinueWith`.

Comment: You've lead me to the correct solution.  Explicitly declaring `.ContinueWith((Task<string[]> t) => { ... })` then unmasked the next problem, that I was calling `Console.WriteLine(t.Exception.Flatten.ToString)` instead of `Console.WriteLine(t.Exception.Flatten().ToString())`.  After fixing this, I was able to remove the explicit lambda parameter declaration, and the compiler was happy.

Comment: @MCattle Interesting that the missing parentheses there would make the compiler unable to decide between the two overloads. I was a little suspicious of my own answer because I didn't ever remember having to explicitly give the lambda input type the countless number of times I've used `ContinueWith` myself. I can't explain why the missing parentheses would make the difference.

Comment: Makes sense to me, because the overload is inferred by the usage, and if there's a syntax error in the usage, then the correct overload cannot be inferred.